# Probability 12 families meeting

Tags: probability

please help me to find the solution of this.

What is the Probability that 12 families meet 4 times a year an every time only 4 families meeting together  without repetition so that each family sees the other family only once without repetition.

For example at the first time will be

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12

What is the 4th probability?

At the second time

3 6 9 12

That is wrong because the families 9 & 12 should not be together another time

I am waiting for the answer
Best regards

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit or post the question as written? It's a little hard to understand what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as you have structured it

At the second time, a family from the first group of the first time can only meet

- one family from the second group of the first time
- one family from the third group of the first time
- leaving a fourth possibility who cannot be from any of the three groups of the first time

(Perhaps there is only one group of four each time)